# Achieving variables in the local syntax in the Scheme environment

Tags: scheme, racket, local-variables

How we can achieve variables that we defined in the `(local ...)` syntax in Scheme?
For example in this code below,

```
(define (erkan x)
   (local 
      ((define y 10))
      (* x y)))
```

How can I directly get the value of y ?

Comment: I don't understand your question. You are getting the value of `y` there — that's how `x` is multiplied by 10. Do you mean you want to access `y` outside of the function?

Comment: yes, exactly. I want to use y outside of the function-

edit: got the answer. i missed the concept, it is "local" after all. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either this is a strange question, or you didn't phrase it right...  Your sample code uses `y`, so it does have access to it.  Maybe you're trying to get just the value of `y`:

```
(define (erkan x) (local [(define y 10)] y))
```

Or maybe you want to create a kind of an "object thing" -- this is possible, but involves more advanced code.  Here's a quick example just to show you how it's done, (but if you're going through HtDP, you're better off leaving this for later).

```
(define (erkan x)
  (local [(define y 10)
          (define (handler message)
            (cond
              [(eq? message 'get-x) x]
              [(eq? message 'get-y) y]
              [(eq? message 'compute) (* x y)]
              [else (error "bad message")]))]
    handler))
(define some-erkan (erkan 3))
(some-erkan 'get-x)
(some-erkan 'get-y)
(some-erkan 'compute)
```

(Note BTW that this is not proper Scheme, but the teaching student dialects used in HtDP.)

Comment: yes, studying HtDP.
when i call (erkan 3), result is (lambda (a1) ...) in DrScheme. It is interesting (:
What is the name of this method? maybe i can look at it from the book.

Comment: It's really best to just go with the book in order -- it will also cover some of the more advanced things, and in a way that will be more understandable than some random piece of code...

Answer (score 2):

You *are* accessing `y` when you're doing `(* x y)`.

If you want to access `y` from outside of the `local`-block: you can't do that. Any definitions made inside a `local`-block are local to that block and cannot be accessed from outside.